# Array copying confusion

Tags: java, arrays

```
int[] arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int[] copy = arr;
copy[4] = 2;
System.out.println(arr[4]);
```

So it prints out 2 but I don't know why it would do that when arr doesn't equal copy. Shouldn't it still be 5 or am I dumb?

Comment: Arrays are objects and therefore accessed by reference. Therefore arr and copy are pointing to the same object.

Comment: That’s not how to copy arrays, you copied a link to memory location of the array and updated the same array. To clone/copy array https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/array-copy-in-java/amp/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So it prints out 2 but I don't know why it would do that when arr
>   doesn't equal copy. Shouldn't it still be 5?

No, this is the expected behaviour. This is because `copy` and `arr` are referring to the same array object.

Create a copy in an immutable way as follows:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        int[] copy = Arrays.copyOf(arr, arr.length);
        copy[4] = 2;
        System.out.println(arr[4]);
        System.out.println(copy[4]);

        int[] anotherCopy = arr.clone();
        anotherCopy[4] = 2;
        System.out.println(arr[4]);
        System.out.println(anotherCopy[4]);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
5
2
5
2
```

Comment: Thank you Arvind Kumar Avinash I didn't know that they would copy each other if they did that

Comment: To copy an array without changing size, use `copy = arr.clone();`, which is a lot more efficient. The `Arrays.copyOf(...)` is for changing the size of the copied array, which is why it *requires* the `newLength` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making a separate array, your compiler is just assigning a pointer to the the original array.  In other words,  both of the arrays are actually the same data underneath but with different names and pointers.  A change to one will affect the other.

Comment: `copy = arr` is not a "shallow copy", it is an *assignment*, not a copy at all. `Arrays.copyOf(arr, arr.length)` and `arr.clone()` are both examples of shallow copies. Since the array is not an object array, but an array of primitives, a shallow copy is also a deep copy, since there is no "depth" to copy.

Comment: @Andreas Thanks for explaining. I will edit my answer to comply with this.